# capture-specific-columns and mask the column

Tags: shell, unix, nawk

I am trying to write the script to capture and mask the specific column.I need to have the 4 column with clear text and also mask it too in output file .I am not sure how to mask the same column

Pls help me in rewriting the below command or new command

```
input.txt
---------
AA | BB | CC | 123456

output.txt
---------
BB | 123456 | 12xx56
```

Script I wrote

```
cat input.txt | nawk -F '|' '{print $2  "|" $4 "|" $4} >output.txt
```

Comment: will the value in column 4 always be 6 chars? If not, then edit your sample to indicate what you expect to happen with other sizes. Good luck.

Comment: The value in the 4 th column is fixed length always 6 chars

Answer (score 0):

```
nawk -F '|' '{print $2  "|" $4 "|" substr($4, 1,3) "xx" substr($4,6,2)}' input.txt > output.txt
```

**output**

```
BB | 123456| 12xx56
```

Assuming you don't really need the leading and trailing spaces, I would make it

```
nawk -F '|' '{gsub(/  */, "", $0);print $2  "|" $4 "|" substr($4, 1,2) "xx" substr($4,5,2)}' input.txt > output.txt

cat output.txt
BB|123456|12xx56
```

**final solution**

```
echo "AA | BB | CC | 12345678" \
| awk -F '|' '{gsub(/  */, "", $0)
  #dbg print "length$4=" (length($4)-4)
  masking=sprintf("%"(length($4)-4)"s", " ") ; gsub(/ /, "x", masking)
  print $2  "|" $4 "|" substr($4, 1,2) masking substr($4,(length($4)-1),2)
}'

BB|12345678|12xxxx78
```

I using `echo "..."` to simplfy the testing process. You can take that out, replace with `input.txt > output.txt` and the end of the line and it will work as before.

I've added the `(length($4)-1)` to make the position of the 2nd to last char on $4 dynamic, based on the length of what ever word is in $4.

IHTH

Comment: Yes .In the command where are you masking with xx?I need to mask the column to mask too

Comment: lets assume the column is not fixed and I need to keep last 2 digit and first 2 digit in the output all the middle should be xxxxxx Then what would be the command